# problem in the layout of a Mind map with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I create a mindmap with 4 concept nodes, with a precious your help for the formatting the map in A4 paper.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[article, 12pt, oneside, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mindmap,
    grow cyclic, text width=4cm, align=flush center,
    every node/.style={concept},
    concept color=orange!40,
    %root/.style= {concept color=black!40,font=\large\bfseries,text width=12em},
    level 1/.style={level distance=8cm,sibling angle=90},
    level 2/.style={level distance=6cm,sibling angle=45},
    level 3/.style={level distance=6cm,sibling angle=45}]

\node [root concept, scale=2] {\textbf{Root concept}}
   child [concept color=blue!30] { node {Classification}
        child { node {first classification}}
        child { node {first classification}}
        child { node {first classification}}
    }
    child [concept color=green!30] { node {One concept}
        child [concept color=green!40]{ node {description \\ of concept 1}}
       % child { node {B}}
    }
    child [concept color=yellow!30] { node {Second \\ concept}
        child { node {Environment}}
        child { node {concept two}}
        child [concept color=red!40] { node {concept \\ three}
                child { node {Description of child concept one}}  
                child { node {Description of child concept two}}
                child { node {Description of child concept three}}      
        }
    }
    child [concept color=teal!40]  { node {Other concept}
        child { node {description concept}}
        child { node {description concept}}
        child { node {description concept}}
        child { node {...}}
        child { node {...}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{caption here}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which produce the following mindmap:
[image]

Unfortunately, I need to insert a new concept node but when I introduce it the layout has an abnormal behavior.

**My new LaTex code is**

```
\documentclass[article, 12pt, oneside, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mindmap,
    grow cyclic, text width=4cm, align=flush center,
    every node/.style={concept},
    concept color=orange!40,
    %root/.style= {concept color=black!40,font=\large\bfseries,text width=12em},
    level 1/.style={level distance=8cm,sibling angle=90},
    level 2/.style={level distance=6cm,sibling angle=45},
    level 3/.style={level distance=6cm,sibling angle=45}]

\node [root concept, scale=2] {\textbf{Root concept}}
   child [concept color=blue!30] { node {Classification}
        child { node {first classification}}
        child { node {first classification}}
        child { node {first classification}}
    }
    child [concept color=green!30] { node {One concept}
        child [concept color=green!40]{ node {description \\ of concept 1}}
       % child { node {B}}
    }
    child [concept color=yellow!30] { node {Second \\ concept}
        child { node {Environment}}
        child { node {concept two}}
        child [concept color=red!40] { node {concept \\ three}
                child { node {Description of child concept one}}  
                child { node {Description of child concept two}}
                child { node {Description of child concept three}}      
        }
    }
    child [concept color=teal!40]  { node {Other concept}
        child { node {description concept}}
        child { node {description concept}}
        child { node {description concept}}
        child { node {...}}
        child { node {...}}
    }
  child [concept color=green!80] { node {\textbf{Five concept}}     
     child [concept color=blue!30]{ node {child concept}}

    };
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{caption here}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Can you help me to adjust the layout?
The position of the five concepts is not is not bound, the important thing is that the figure maintains a 'visual harmony'.

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to add a fifth level 1 child, then you need to change the angle from 90 to 72 for example.

`level 1/.style={level distance=8cm,sibling angle=72}`

[image]

Comment: I tried to change the angle from 90 to 72 (because 360°/5=72°) but it produce a mindmap in which the nodes are mutually superposed.

Comment: I successfully compiled your "new LaTeX code" with 3 changes: (1) 72 instead of 90, (2) one less closing bracket and (3) suppress the blank line after the last `child`. It gives me a mindmap with five children.