# tikZ - mindmap - How to increase the font size of text in a node concept

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I have just drawn a mind map with your help in a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282101/problem-in-the-layout-of-a-mind-map-with-tikz/282115?noredirect=1#comment680014_282115).

Once I print the document, the font is too small and does not read very well.
Before to reduce the length of text I am looking for a way to increase the font size.
I looked for on the manual but I did not found it.

Can you help me?

Comment: adding `font=\large` in the level style specification should work...

Comment: @Rmano Yes, but it may be rather too much. The default level styles reduce the font size for later levels, so you do not necessarily want to make them larger than normal text size. You may just want `\small` or `\normalsize` or whatever. Note that you may also need to adjust the size of the concept nodes in order to accommodate larger text.

Comment: Does [my answer to a related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281947/tikz-fill-concepts-in-mindmaps-nicely/282037#282037) help?

Answer (score 3):

Probably [you should read @cfr answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281947/tikz-fill-concepts-in-mindmaps-nicely/282037#282037) --- that one is a more comprehensive one.

But to adjust things on the spot, you can hack like that:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,shadows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        mindmap, concept color=blue!70, grow cyclic,
    ]
  \node[concept] {Root}
        child[concept]{ node[concept]{Level 1 A} } 
        child[concept]{ node[concept]{Level 1 B}  
            child[concept, font=\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont]{
                node[concept]{Level 2 10pt} } 
            child[concept, font=\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont]{
                node[concept]{Level 2 12pt} } 
            child[concept, font=\fontsize{14pt}{17pt}\selectfont]{
                node[concept]{Level 2 14pt} } 
         };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and remember that maybe you need to tweak `text width` and `minimum size` keys.

[image: Example results]